# Entity Framework: self referencing tree with different ParrentID

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have class like this:

```
  class Tree
  {
     [Key]
     public int TreeID { get; set; }
     public int? ParentID { get; set; }
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public virtual Tree Parrent { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Tree> Children { get; set; }
 }
```

And configuration class :

```
class TreeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Tree>
{
    public TreeConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasOptional(d => d.Parrent)
            .WithMany(p => p.Children)
            .HasForeignKey( d => d.ParentID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }

}
```

It works good, but what I want is to child node use ID (from parrent node) for ParentID, not TreeID.

It should work like this:
Each node has an id - that is ID - and id of its parent - that is ParentID. TreeID is primary key and it has nothing to do with child-parent mapping - it's for database only.

I can't change the columns so I it must be this way

Answer (score 0):

Well..  apparently it has something to do with the fact that FKs must always point to primary keys. So it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use your "ID" as a unique column - e.g. use a unique index for it? 
Then you have the same semantics like you would have if ID would be the PK..